# Lubuntu login screen keeps on appearing

Tags: lubuntu, login-screen, loop-device

Well I have installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS lubuntu tty1. Was working fine for two days, but a problem now. When I try to login, the login page keeps on reappearing  repeatedly without logging me in. Enlighten me on this.

Comment: If you have limited space in $HOME (your user directory), your gui login will fail - however text terminal does not. It won't impact an already logged in user until they logout & try to re-login.  You can login via text terminal to check space (`df` or disk-free), but this is only one such cause (the most common for me anyway)

Comment: Yeah, that was my problem too. Thanks so much for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  How I fixed it was by clicking on the gear beside the "Sign In" button.

If it's an option, select "Ubuntu on Wayland".
If it's not, well I don't know that much about Ubuntu.  Sorry!

I hope this helps!